# how can manage session on different web application from one website in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session-state

I am working on classified ads project this project consist on 3 different solutions (website)
in Visual studio 2010

```
1. Classified Ads (main project include all type of ads)
2. Property Ads ( for property ads)
3. Auto-mobile Ads (for Auto-mobile Ads)
```

I have manage all login and session management in main solution (1.Classified Ads)

so now I want to manage session for other two solution (2,3) on the base of main solution (1)

mean if user login from main solution (website) then user can access other two solution with this session that I created in main website.

How can I do this? and what will be best solution to manage these different website ?

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net Session is working only for one user inside single application. So there is no built-in way to do that.
I suppose that you can use SqlServer Session State and dig ASP.NET table structure in database. Base on that knowledge it could be possible to manually relate IIS to the same table records. Anyway it is very tricky way and there is no proof that it will be working in a future (table structure could be changed but asp.net developers in any time)

**Edited**
BTW you can implement your own session provider - this way you will always know what and where located and how to deal with it.

Here is a small example of custom session provider implementation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178588.aspx

And here is another one (you can download the source code there via Download Class File link)

http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/building-a-custom-asp-net-2-0-session-state-provider/